# Stored procedure returns nullable DateTime instead of a varchar

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a problem where I have defined a column as a varchar in the stored procedure but yet when I add it to my C# program, EntityFramework uses the original field type of DateTime nullable.  I am think the problem could be in the second select statement since I use the same field name but not 100% sure.

Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT
      1                                         AS [SORT]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.RecDate, 120)        AS [RecDate]
      ,t1.Program                               AS [Program]
      ,t1.Currency                              AS [CURRENCY]
      ,t1.SupplierName                          AS [SupplierName]
      ,t1.SupplierAccount                       AS [SupplierAccount]
      ,t1.RecStatus                             AS [RecStatus]
      ,t4.Type                                  AS [TYPE]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.Date, 120)           AS [PiDate]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.DiscountedDate, 120) AS [DiscountedDate]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.DueDate, 120)        AS [DueDate]                                
      ,t1.PaymentAmount                         AS [Payment]

FROM orb_RootRecords t1
LEFT JOIN orb_SupplierRecords t3 on t3.OrbianAccountId = t1.SupplierAccount
LEFT JOIN orb_AccountType t4 on t4.Id = t3.AccountTypeId
WHERE FLOOR(CAST(t1.RecDate as float)) = FLOOR(CAST(@runDate as float))
--ORDER BY [SORT], [Program]  ,[CURRENCY] ,[RecDate] ,[SupplierName] ,[SupplierAccount],[RecStatus] ,[TYPE],[PiDate] ,[DiscountedDate] ,[Payment]

UNION

SELECT 2 AS [SORT], [RecDate], Program AS [Program], [CURRENCY], null AS [SupplierName], null AS [SupplierAccount], null AS [RecStatus], null AS [TYPE], null AS [PiDate], null AS [DiscountedDate], null AS [DueDate]
,SUM (PaymentAmount) AS [Payment]
FROM orb_RootRecords t2
where FLOOR(CAST(t2.RecDate as float)) = FLOOR(CAST(@runDate as float))

Group by [RecDate], [Program], [CURRENCY]
ORDER BY  [RecDate], [Program], [CURRENCY], [Sort], [SupplierName], [SupplierAccount], [RecStatus], [TYPE], [PiDate], [DiscountedDate], [DueDate], [Payment]
```

EntityFramework Result:

```
public partial class orb_rpt_reconciliation_report_Result
{
    public int SORT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RecDate { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string CURRENCY { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAccount { get; set; }
    public string RecStatus { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string PiDate { get; set; }
    public string DiscountedDate { get; set; }
    public string DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Payment { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting to see public string RecDate { get; set; } rather than what is shown above.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be consistent with how you treat `RecDate`: either always convert to to a string, or don't do so, ever. SQL Server will change data types if it needs to to make a query or compare "work". The only way to ensure consistency in the result is to be consistent in what you ask it to do.

Comment: Assuming you always want RecDate to be a string, while not put `CONVERT(VARCHAR, t2.RecDate, 120)` into the second query in your `UNION`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two comments - changed [RecDate] to convert(varchar, t2.RecDate, 120) As [RecDate] and was able to have the output class correct.